# AWS: EC2 instance No Data Received

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS. I set up an instance and deployed a Django App on it by following this [tutorial](http://nickpolet.com/blog/deploying-django-on-aws/1/)

But when I try to access the instance from the browser via the ip or the public DNS it returns **'No data received'**, **'ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'**. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed to solve this:

1. Went to EC2 instances
2. Click on instance
3. Go to Security Groups column and click on the security group selected.
4. In the lower panel, select Inbound >  Edit > Add Rule
5. Under Add Rule, select Type as HTTP and Save.